# Building SQL Query To Remove PowerDNS Records

Tags: mysql, mariadb, powerdns

I am trying to build a SQL query that removes domains from a PowerDNS database. The tables are called, domains and domains_status. I want to delete both records only if domains_status where the columns name domain_regStatus = 0. The ID value is the same for both domains and domain_status.

Here is an example of how the database looks,

[pdns_domain_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4IT0.png)
[pdns_domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkiyX.png)

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DELETE` with a join between the tables

```
DELETE d, ds
FROM domains AS d
JOIN domain_status AS ds on d.id = ds.domain_id
WHERE ds.domain_regStatus = 0
```

If `domain_status.domain_id` is declared as a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you only need to delete from the `domains` table, it will automatically delete from `domain_status`. So change to:

```
DELETE d
FROM domains AS d
JOIN domain_status AS ds on d.id = ds.domain_id
WHERE ds.domain_regStatus = 0
```